# add all rows of multiple tables into one and group using linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Hi i am trying to create a search query with `entityframework`
I am doing something like this

```
model = _context.articles.where(combination 1)
model2 = _context.tags.where(combination 2).select(x=> new {article=..})
model3 = _context.keywords.where(combination 3).select(x=> new {article=..})
```

I am not generating one model as its not possible or out of my capacity to create such query but now since i have 3 models with similar columns all i want to do is merge them into one and remove duplicates. 
I don't know if this is good approach but is it possible?

Comment: Questions for you, 1. Are these tables sharing any relationships with each other? 2. Where do you see the possibility of duplicates from different tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use [union](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/204/how-to-use-union-operator-with-entity-framework) and [distinct](https://blog.udemy.com/linq-distinct/) methods as following:

```
var result =  model.Union(model2).Union(model3).Distinct().ToList();
```